# Start an Intent where the Class Name is a Variable?

Tags: android, database, android-intent

I'm trying to access an intent from a string variable that represents the intent's name, `nIntent`.

**Question:** If I replace the variable `nIntent` with the `QueryDisplay.class` name, it fires correctly, but if I use a variable, why do I get the typical `No Activity found to handle Intent { act=QueryDisplay.class (has extras) }`?

I don't get it because it works fine hard-coded (it's in the manifest).  Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                String url = "";
                url = (String) v.getTag();

                int nI = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("intent");
                String nIntent = c.getString(nI);

                int tvTitle = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title");
                String title = c.getString(tvTitle);

                int tvLabel = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("label");
                String label = c.getString(tvLabel);

                String queryKey = "SELECT * FROM " + label + " ORDER BY `_id` ASC";

                //Intent i = new Intent(nIntent);<- This doesn't?? work
                Intent i = new Intent(this, QueryDisplay.class);<- This works
                i.putExtra("QUERY_KEY", queryKey);
                i.putExtra("url", url);
                i.putExtra("TITLE", title);
                i.putExtra("LABEL", label);
                QueryDisplay.this.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

UPDATE:  Here is the correct code:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                String url = "";
                url = (String) v.getTag();

                int nI = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("intent");
                String intent = c.getString(nI);
                Class<?> nIntent = null;
                try {
                    nIntent = Class.forName(intent);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                int tvTitle = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title");
                String title = c.getString(tvTitle);

                int tvLabel = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("label");
                String label = c.getString(tvLabel);

                String queryKey = "SELECT * FROM " + label + " ORDER BY `_id` ASC";

                Intent i = new Intent(QueryDisplay.this, nIntent);
                i.putExtra("QUERY_KEY", queryKey);
                i.putExtra("url", url);
                i.putExtra("TITLE", title);
                i.putExtra("LABEL", label);
                QueryDisplay.this.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `nIntent` is a String, not a `Class` object. If you look at the [Intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), you'll see that the only constructor that accepts a single String requires that the string represents an action, not a class.

If you want to convert a String to a Class, I think you can do so with the [Class.forName](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: Thnx!  That's what was needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

Intent call should be same in both the cases whether you are using hardcoded Queryclass name or nIntent.

Rather than using 'this' use [Class].this  in intent call.

and for dynamic class from db just return classname in the string not the whole intent name as a string as while creating an Intent you need to pass the context. Still you face problem ... revert back with problem. Cheers!

Comment: Thnx, I originally was using [Class].this.  Just this last time I didn't but thnx for the advice.